# GlassMapper: Unpublishable items are null in preview

Tags: glass-mapper, mvc, publishing

When an item is set to unpublishable, all methods to get the item for a rendering with GlassMapper return `null`.

```
public class PageHeaderController : GlassController
{
    public override ActionResult Header()
    {
        BaseItem model = SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<BasePage>(); // null
        model = GetLayoutItem<BasePage>(); // null
        model = SitecoreContext.GetItem<BasePage>(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource); // null
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

How can we get the item in that case to be able to provide a publishing preview for editors for items that are set to be published in the future?

The problem occurs whether we use the "Never Publish" setting or set the version to unpublishable or even when the version is set to be published in the future.

The preview is really running with the master database.[image]

Comment: How do you obtain `SitecoreContext`? From what I know there is no static method `SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak `SitecoreContext` is a member of `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassController`.

Comment: Right, I missed that.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I am understanding your question correctly. The business case is that your authors create an item, but said item is not yet ready for publishing. Either via custom workflow, Standard Values, manual setting by the authors, etc. the "Never Publish" field is checked to prevent accidental/premature publishing. However, the authors want to be able to view the rendered page for the item using the "Preview" feature. Is that correct?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Yes, that is the business case.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you are using the "Never Publish" setting for this rather than using Workflow? I can post this with further detail as an answer but only if you request it, since it doesn't technically answer your original question. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/workflows_and_the_workbox

Comment: It does not matter whether I use the "Never Publish" setting or set the version to unpublishable or even when the version is set to be published in the future.

Comment: Glass is using `Sitecore.Context.Item`. This shouid not be `null`. Are you sure you are running your preview against the master db?

Comment: @maz Yes, the preview is running with the master db:

Comment: @Residuum At the end of the day, I think you may need to re-evaluate your implementation. It looks like you are trying to use the publishable settings to develop functionality that is already included with Sitecore OOTB. Before proceeding with your current implementation, make sure that you are familiar with and understand Sitecore's Workflow feature, and make sure that what you are trying to do cannot be accomplished using the OOTB workflow features. The link to the workflow docs is at the end of my last comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behavior for the Preview feature. The purpose of this feature is to show you what the page will look like once published. Therefore the behavior you're encountering sort of makes sense, considering the page would simply not be published. To be fair, a more graceful approach (e.g. warning message) would be appreciated.

There are a couple of ways to get around it.

(1) If it's just for a one-off preview, you can change the preview URL like so. If Sitecore generates:

```
http://mysite.local/?sc_itemid=%7BFC3FE8C5-FAE6-4C67-8F21-B3757D143D4A%7D&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en-US&sc_site=mysite
```

Change it to:

```
http://mysite.local/?sc_itemid=%7BFC3FE8C5-FAE6-4C67-8F21-B3757D143D4A%7D&sc_mode=normal&sc_lang=en-US&sc_site=mysite&sc_database=master
```

Note the `sc_mode` and `sc_database` parameters.

(2) In code, you could disable site filtering by setting `Sitecore.Context.Site.DisableFiltering` to `true`. More details in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20390596/1327412

Comment: unfortunately GlassMapper, or at least the implementation I'm using, does not factor in the setting `Sitecore.Context.Site.DisableFiltering`, so anytime we try to cast the Never Publish item into a Glass entity, it will return null.